# MySQL multiple tables conditional filter

Tags: mysql

I want to check the validity of a `user_id`, from a table of users that contains three types of users (type `i`, `c` and `p`).

For users of type `c` to be valid, the current user.party_id has to be present in the `customer_partner` table against the supplied `$PNR`.

For users of type `i` to be valid, the current user.party_id has top be present in the `installer_partner` table against the supplied `$PNR`.

For users of type `p` to be valid, the current user.party_id has to be the supplied `$PNR`.

I want the returned row to be the user details if valid, or no rows if invalid. I have tried a couple of ways to do this, but unsuccessfully.

EXAMPLE 1: I am using a CASE in the select then placing a `v` or `e` value in the resulting column, then filtering out in the `WHERE` statement, but this gives me `Unknown column 'valid_user' in 'where clause'` error.

```
SELECT
    CASE users.party_type 
        WHEN 'c' 
        THEN IF(users.party_id IN (SELECT pnrcus.customer_id 
                                   FROM customer_partner AS pnrcus
                                   WHERE pnrcus.partner_id = '.$PNR.'),'v','e')
        WHEN 'i' 
        THEN IF(users.party_id IN (SELECT pnrins.installer_id 
                                   FROM installer_partner AS pnrins
                                   WHERE pnrins.partner_id = '.$PNR.'),'v','e')
        WHEN 'p'
        THEN IF(users.party_id = '.$PNR.','v','e')
        ELSE 'e'
    END AS valid_user,
    users.email_user_id, 
    users.party_id, 
    users.person_id, 
    users.first_name, 
    users.last_name 
FROM users AS users
WHERE LCASE(users.email_user_id) = LCASE('.$UID.') 
AND users.password = '.$PWD.'
AND valid_user = 'v'
AND users.account_status = 'a'
```

EXAMPLE 2: I am using `OR` statements in the `WHERE` part of the sql. This returns the wrong rows.

```
SELECT
    users.party_type 
    users.email_user_id, 
    users.party_id, 
    users.person_id, 
    users.first_name, 
    users.last_name
FROM users AS users
WHERE LCASE(users.email_user_id) = LCASE('.$UID.') 
AND users.password = '.$PWD.'
AND users.account_status = 'a'
AND (
    parties.party_type = 'c' 
    AND users.party_id IN (SELECT pnrcus.customer_id 
                           FROM sma_customer_partner AS pnrcus
                           WHERE pnrcus.partner_id = .$PNR.')
    ) OR (
    parties.party_type = 'i' 
    AND users.party_id IN (SELECT pnrins.installer_id 
                           FROM sma_installer_partner AS pnrins
                           WHERE pnrins.partner_id = .$PNR.')
    ) OR (
    parties.party_type = 'p' 
    AND users.party_id = '.$PNR.'
    )
```

Comment: Your tags are incompatible

Comment: Your statement is not clear to me. I do not understand

Comment: mysq and sql server are 2 different beasts

Comment: sql-server tag == Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Sorry! Got it! Changing it now. Thanks! This is a MySQL Question

Comment: Can you show some sample data?Word problems are difficult,a visual aid would make things easier.

Comment: You could move it to a `HAVING valid_user = 'v'` clause, but frankly, I'd normally `LEFT JOIN` the tables and require the primary key (or non-NULLable column) of one of those two not to be NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix to your problem is to add a `HAVING`  clause for the column in the resultset you created:

```
SELECT
    CASE users.party_type 
        WHEN 'c' 
        THEN IF(users.party_id IN (SELECT pnrcus.customer_id 
                                   FROM customer_partner AS pnrcus
                                   WHERE pnrcus.partner_id = '.$PNR.'),'v','e')
        WHEN 'i' 
        THEN IF(users.party_id IN (SELECT pnrins.installer_id 
                                   FROM installer_partner AS pnrins
                                   WHERE pnrins.partner_id = '.$PNR.'),'v','e')
        WHEN 'p'
        THEN IF(parties.party_id = '.$PNR.','v','e')
        ELSE 'e'
    END AS valid_user,
    users.email_user_id, 
    users.party_id, 
    users.person_id, 
    users.first_name, 
    users.last_name 
FROM users AS users
WHERE LCASE(users.email_user_id) = LCASE('.$UID.') 
AND users.password = '.$PWD.'
AND users.account_status = 'a'
HAVING valid_user = 'v'
```

But, frankly, I'd do this:

```
SELECT
    users.party_type 
    users.email_user_id, 
    users.party_id, 
    users.person_id, 
    users.first_name, 
    users.last_name
FROM users AS users
LEFT JOIN customer_partner AS pnrcus
   ON pnrcus.partner_id = '.$PNR.'
   AND pnrcus.customer_id = users.party_id
   AND users.party_type = 'c'
LEFT JOIN installer_partner AS pnrins
   ON pnrins.partner_id = '.$PNR.'
   AND pnrins.installer_id = users.party_id
   AND pnrins.party_type = 'i'
WHERE 
   LCASE(users.email_user_id) = LCASE('.$UID.') 
   AND users.password = '.$PWD.'
   AND users.account_status = 'a'
   AND (
      ( users.party_type  ='p' AND users,party_id = '.$PNR.' )
      OR pnrcus.partner_id IS NOT NULL
      OR pnrins.partner_id IS NOT NULL
   )
GROUP BY users.email_user_id;
```

Note BTW that this is *very* slow:

```
LCASE(users.email_user_id) = LCASE('.$UID.')
```

You might want to use a collation where 'A'='a' == true (all _ci ones are), or store it lowercase, and provide it lowercase. As it stands it cannot use an index.

Comment: forgot the `AND pnrcus.customer_id = users.party_id`, added.

Comment: Awesome! so close yet so far. Thanks for the even better method suggestion!